# Custom Hooks with TypeScript - return value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript, react-tsx

I'm trying to experiment custom Hooks with TS (quite new on both). This `useOption` should take etiher a `number` or a `boolean`, and return the `value` with the same type, and the changer function. This because an option should be `<input>` with 'range' type, and one `<input>` as checkbox (but this could be extended with other input types). So I have an `<Options />` component like this:

```
const Options = () => {
  const [pieces, setPieces] = useOption(10);
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useOption(5);
  const [sound, setSound] = useOption(false);

  return (
    <div className='Options'>
      <input
        type='range'
        value={pieces}
        onChange={setPieces}
        min='5'
        max='25' />
      <p>{pieces}</p>
      <input
        type='range'
        value={speed}
        onChange={setSpeed}
        min='1'
        max='10' />
      <p>{speed}</p>
      <input
        type='checkbox'
        value={sound}
        onChange={setSound} />
      <p>{sound ? 'Sound on' : 'Sound off'}</p>
      <button
        className='start-btn'
        onClick={handleClick}>Start game</button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

And a custom hook useOption.

```
const useOption = (initialValue: number | boolean) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (typeof(e.currentTarget.value) === 'boolean') {
      const newValue = !value;
      setValue(newValue);     
    } 
    else {
      const newValue = Number(e.currentTarget.value);
      setValue(newValue)
    }
  };

  return [value, handleChange] as const;
};
```

I thought, that with the `typeof` type guard and the use of `const` (like written in [this](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/hooks#custom-hooks) page), TS recognized the returned type, but I still have errors about it, showing me the error over the `value` property.

```
Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2256, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'
```

Any suggestion about to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the hook generic

```
const useOption = <T extends number | boolean>(initialValue: T) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (typeof e.currentTarget.value === 'boolean') {
      const newValue = !value;
      setValue(newValue as T);
    } else {
      const newValue = Number(e.currentTarget.value);
      setValue(newValue as T);
    }
  };

  return [value, handleChange] as const;
};
```

And pass type in the component

```
export default function App() {
  const [pieces, setPieces] = useOption<number>(10);
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useOption<number>(5);
  const [sound, setSound] = useOption<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <div className="Options">
      <input
        type="range"
        value={pieces}
        onChange={setPieces}
        min="5"
        max="25"
      />
      <p>{pieces}</p>
      <input type="range" value={speed} onChange={setSpeed} min="1" max="10" />
      <p>{speed}</p>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={sound} onChange={setSound} /> // use checked in here
      <p>{sound ? 'Sound on' : 'Sound off'}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-aivwb7?file=App.tsx)

Comment: All answers should be like this.